# Convert string datetime format into integer time in seconds in python

Tags: python-2.7, datetime-format

My input is input_time = "May 5 2016 11:29:32". 
Expected output should be in seconds or milli seconds which is type of integer i.e., output_time = 2424241313113.
The above conversion should be done in python. How to do this conversion?

Comment: Have you looked at `datetime` yet?

Comment: As Ignacio mentioned, check out the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module. More specifically, [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to convert date time into epoch seconds (dated starting from 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970)

In Python 3.3+

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('May 5 2016 11:29:32','%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S').timestamp()
```

In Python 2.7.9

```
datetime.strptime('May 5 2016 11:29:32','%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S').strftime('%s')
```

Note that `strftime('%s')` use your local time zone.

Comment: Could you tell me, the value returns is in secs or in milli secs?

Comment: If the value getting in negative value, what does it meant for?

Comment: `.strftime('%s')` is not supported by Python and it is not portable. If the input is the local time then `time.mktime(dt.timetuple())` could be used. `mktime()` and `.timestamp()` that uses it may fail if python has no access to a historical timezone database on a given platform or if the input time is ambiguous or non-existent in the local timezone.

Comment: @user27 the value is seconds

Comment: can you give example of when the value is negative? If you try to convert a datetime before 1970, like `datetime.strptime('May 5 1016 11:29:32','%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S').timestamp()` it returns `OverflowError: timestamp out of range`

Comment: If my time is "00:56" then the given function returns value in negative.